# Letter with circle above -- not a dot -- in math mode

Tags: math-mode, stacking-symbols

I need to typeset letter with a circle above it in math. `\dot A` does a very close result, but I need something that looks like `\circ`, not like `\cdot`.

Edit: there is awesome answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character), but Detexify failed for me, and I tried looking up tables, but haven't found what I needed.

Comment: `\mathring{A}`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Sorry, I know that awesome site, but it have not given me answer.

Comment: I was not thinking of detexify, but of `texdoc symbols` given as the first option in the top answer - table 164 Math mode accents, the same table containg `\dot`.  That not only answers your question, but tells you how to find answers to similar questions.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks. As I mentioned, I was searching there, but haven't succeeded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Use \overset{\circ}{X} or \mathring{X} for letter X say
```

Comment: `\mathring` - exactly what i needed!

Comment: I'd avoid the first: `\mathring` is the correct answer